# mySQL Order By String

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following function to SELECT and ORDER some images from my DB, but the ORDER does not work.

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM modzzz_articles_screenshots WHERE entry_id='".$aDataEntry['id']."'";
$qryr=mysql_query($qry) or die("Error selecting: ".mysql_error());

while($qryrow = mysql_fetch_array($qryr)) {

   $media_book_id = $qryrow['media_id'];
   $qry2="SELECT * FROM bx_photos_main WHERE ID='".$media_book_id."' ORDER BY Title DESC";
   $qryr2=mysql_query($qry2) or die("Error selecting: ".mysql_error());

   while($qryrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($qryr2)) {

        $photo_book_id = $qryrow2['ID'];
        $a = array ('ID' => $aAuthor['ID'], 'Avatar' => $photo_book_id);
        $aMedia_book_icon = BxDolService::call('photos', 'get_image', array($a, 'file'), 'Search');
        $aMedia_book_iconUrl = $aMedia_book_icon['file'];
        $sRet .='<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="'.$aMedia_book_iconUrl.'" title=""><img src="'.$aMedia_book_iconUrl.'"></a>';

   }
}
```

`ORDER BY title ASC` or `DESC` always returns the same thing.

Is there any error?

Could the problem be that the Title column is not an INT value but VARCHAR?

If that's the problem, I cannot change the column Title, is there an easy way to order the result anyway?

Thanks

Comment: which other data u need?

Comment: your only getting one result from the second query ... you select it using WHERE ID=? ... the order will do nothing ! is ID an auto_increment column ?

Comment: Can you isolate query, execute it in mysql (not via php) and post here select and results? This can help.

Comment: Include your table schema and also some sample data from each table ....

Comment: By the way, the use of the mysql_* functions is [officially discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). You should instead be using MySQLi or PDO, which will make your code much more secure, clearer and easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: @ManseUK that's not only one ID, that's a mySQL loop, so it will be more IDs passed from the first SELECT..

Comment: @ManseUK I don't think the second query is only returning one result, or else he would not need a while loop to get all the rows of data it returned.

Comment: I think the second query return only one line because of 'id' field, wich I suppose to be a auto_increment because are not `id_bx_photo_main` (with a 1:n or something) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Here you limit only one record:

```
   $qry2="SELECT * FROM bx_photos_main WHERE ID='".$media_book_id."' ORDER BY Title DESC";
```

So, order ASC or DESC will be the same ever.
Supposing `$media_book_id = 1;`

```
SELECT * FROM bx_photos_main WHERE ID='".$media_book_id."' ORDER BY Title DESC
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM bx_photos_main WHERE ID='".$media_book_id."' ORDER BY Title DESC
```

Will output EVER (with your table structure)

```
id | title | file
-----------------------
01 | Test  | test.jpg
```

Because I have not another line to order ascending or descending.

If I have two lines, it will output for `ASC`:

```
id | title | file
-----------------------
01 | bar   | test.jpg
02 | foo   | test.jpg
```

And for `DESC`:

```
id | title | file
-----------------------
01 | foo   | test.jpg
02 | bar   | test.jpg
```

Comment: What does it mean? How do I SELECT then the right values? I am confused

Comment: If you select only one ID, the `$query2` wich result only one line. Will update my answer.